# Access my Asp.Net website through Public IP hosted in my Intranet

Tags: asp.net, iis

Till date, i had a intranet website hosted in our local infrastructure. For a specific requirement, i need to allow a external vendor application to contact my site thro internet to post some value through query string i.e. the external vendor application will post some data through querystring value to a Asp.Net page in my asp.net website. I have asked our network team to allow the vendor application to connect to our intranet site. The network team guy assigned a public IP to the server now and asked the vendor to use the public ip address to call our application.

Even after assigning a public ip, the external application is still not able to call the page. I tried pinging the public ip and it is pinging. I checked the ipaddress of server by visiting www.whatismyip.com from the server and i got the new public ip correctly. I have also manually tried accessing the application thro public ip(http://public_ip) and my asp.net website is not accessbile. What could be the problem? Do i need change anything on the server or router to make my asp.net site work through the public ip?

I'm currently seeing only the server private ip(ip used to identify the server in intranet) in the IPAddress dropdown in inetmgr>Website tab. The public ip is not listed here..This could be a problem?

Please note that i was able to browse my page through the server's private ip as usual. Thanks for your assistance.

Regards,

Bala

Comment: Also check that port 80 is open on that IP address through your firewall. A successful ping provides no indication of this and only indicates the IP address is exposed to the public Internet.

Comment: Update: when i try to access with ipaddress the request is going to the default website on the IIS. Now, how do i make the request to get forwarded to my website...The ipaddress is not seen in the dropdown in inetmgr>Website tab..Any idea?

Comment: Update: I have added a empty host header with port 80. The site is now accessible from the intranet but not in internet. Checking with our network team...

Answer (score 5):

In IIS Manager, click on (select) the site you want on the Internet, then on the right side click on "Bindings".

[image: IIS Manager --> Edit Site --> Bindings]

Make sure there is an entry that specifies the IP address and host header that you want the web site to respond to.

[image]

**IMPORTANT!**

It sounds like your server is operating on an internal LAN. It is *very likely* that the public IP address you want the web site to appear on does not exist on your server! It sounds like your network team may have FORWARDED the outside public IP address to your server's inside LAN address.

*If this is the case*, when you specify your site's bindings DO NOT use the public IP address. Use the internal LAN address on your server where the public IP address has been forwarded. If you are not sure of the address, simply check the web logs for the default site as there should now be log entries from when you hit that site.

Your problem is bindings at this point. If you are hitting the default site, it is because there is no binding for the site that you want and it is hitting the default site instead (which catches everything not bound elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

the problems can be 2:

1. the webserver is not binded to that ip address (if you have two network cards)
2. the website is binded to an url, not to the ip address (i dont know how to say in english) I mean, if you set it up to work as website.com in the iis preferences, it wont work if accessed via the ip address

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how could i change the IIS bindings? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Check the website bindings in IIS and make sure it includes that new public IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how could i change the IIS bindings? Any pointers?